# Why don't my tamed cats teleport to me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I remember that in old versions of Minecraft tamed wolves teleported to me when they were too far away.

Now I have problems getting cats through the Nether: they won't teleport to the Nether (and that's fine) *nor* they will teleport to me once I'm back to the overworld, like wolves used to do IIRC.

Is this normal cat behaviour? Is this normal behaviour for all tamed beasts now? Or are they somehow bugged? **(obviously they are not in sitting stance)**

Can I bring my cats with me, other than travelling solely via overworld?

*(ps: we're talking about multiplayer here, just in case there still are differences with the single player)*

Comment: _(added 3 specific tags, feel free to remove some of them if you don't like them)_

Comment: they might be in unloaded chunks where they are in stasis (as in they won't do **anything**)

Comment: @ratchetfreak so to make this work I need a second player to stay connected in the old location?

Comment: there might also be a max distance to the teleport but yeah a second player (or leading them back to (the always loaded) spawn) will let them teleport

Comment: @ratchetfreak the "(always loaded) spawn" would be 0,0 or my bed, or any player's bed?

Comment: spawn as in 0,0 (or where you go when your bed is gone)

Comment: @ratchetfreak a pity. Well, I'll try to keep other people in the area, then ;)

Comment: Did cats ever teleport in the first place? I've never seen them do so.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie according to [wikia](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Ocelot#Teleportation), yes, though the paragraph regarding the Nether is vague, but apparently suggests it should teleport once I come back to the overworld.

Comment: Oh, right. And now I'm reminded that cats teleporting is how the [Cat Fountain](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iNw2YcAK9Wc&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DiNw2YcAK9Wc) works. Carry on. :)

Answer (score 3):

This might have something to do with the server render distance/your render distance. If the render distance on the server/client is too low, then it's likely that the cats won't teleport to you.

The cats might also be sitting. Right-click on them to make them not sit and (hopefully, if your server/client isn't just plain broken) teleport to you when you get far enough away.

Also, if you'd like your pets to go through a nether portal, you should have them stand in the portal fluid to teleport them there, then you got there, then you're all in the nether by your portal!

Unloaded chunks can cause pets to freeze. This is what happens when your render distance is set too low. If you'd like your pets to teleport to you while you're in the nether, have someone stand close enough to your pets to have their chunk rendered so they are able to teleport to you.

Comment: I think it's the fourth case, I'll try, thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote, it seems like you don't have problems with cats in the overworld teleporting to you while you're in the overworld, or cats in the Nether teleporting to you when you're in the Nether. What you're expecting seems to be cats teleporting from the overworld to the Nether or vice versa.

Well, it doesn't work, never did, not with cats, not with dogs or other pets. They have no clue how Nether portal works and don't have the ability to teleport across dimensions on their own. When you cross into the Nether, the cat in the overworld will sit down and stop moving until you return to the overworld - it can't find your location and teleport or walk to it if you're in a different dimension.

What you can do instead, is to seat the cat next to the portal (on a block level with the portal so you don't have to push it "uphill" and nudge it into the portal. The cat will teleport to the Nether, and you can follow into the Nether - the cat will likely be sitting inside the portal. Rightclick it to make it stand up, and walk to wherever the exit portal is, then repeat the procedure of pushing the sitting cat into the portal there.

Note you must wait at least 30 seconds between the moment the pet exits the portal (definitely, fully walks out of the frame, not just 'moment of arrival' or slides to the edge of obsidian) and the moment it can be send through a portal again (the same or another). Otherwise it will just won't get teleported to the other dimension.

Comment: Are you sure about the "never did" part? When I wrote this, I thought that early wolves did it. Of course that was 7 years ago so who knows.

Comment: @oO I''m not sure about absolute 'never' but they didn't in a long, long time. I'm quite sure they didn't in 1.5.